# CF - Get app guid from app name via rest

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to get via rest call the app guid from app name e.g provide somehow the app name in specified space and get the app guid ?

I try to search in the docs without success, any idea ?
https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/

in the `get app summery` you need to provide the app UUID , I need the opposite....

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/apps/get_app_summary.html

i've tried with the following without success: (unauthorized error - 401  )

**Im admin in this space and the application is running in CF**

```
getAllApps: () => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            rp({
                uri: 'https://' + myAPI + '/v2/apps',
                json: true

            }).then((data) => {
                "use strict";
                console.log("apps data: " + data);
                resolve(data);
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `cf app your-app --guid -v` to see how the CLI does it:
`GET /v2/apps?q=name%3A<appname>&q=space_guid%3A<space-guid>`

https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/apps/list_all_apps.html

Comment: That looks like a new question. With not enough detail. The response code says you're not authorized: Are you talking to the right endpoint (myAPP is what?), as the right user (authentication details), ...

Comment: Done open new question as requested . please see if you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299829/get-app-guid-from-app-name-with-code