# Get app guid from app name - via code

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I've and node application `mainApp`that running on CF space, in this node application im getting **other** application `name` ( that deployed in the same space) and I want to get from it the application **guid** , How I can do it ?

This is what I've tried ( I try to get all apps in this space and search for specific app from the `guid` but I got http `401 - unauthorized` ,

> 1. any idea how can I get from app that deployed to CF the app app guid (suppose I've the app name )
> 2. There is a better way to achieve this ?

```
getAllApps: () => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            rp({
                uri: 'https://' + CF_API + '/v2/apps',
                json: true

            }).then((data) => {
                "use strict";
                console.log("apps data: " + data);
                resolve(data);
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first get the access token and pass it in the header of the request you have in your question.
See the example below that will get the application guid:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

request({
      "method":"POST",
      "uri": "https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token",
      "json": true,
      "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "authorization": "Basic Y2Y6",
        "accept": "application/json"
      },
      "form" : {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "<your Bluemix id>",
        "password": "<your Bluemix password>"
      }
}).then(function(response) {
      return response.access_token;
}).then(function(token) {
  return request({
    "method":"GET",
    "uri": "https://api.ng.bluemix.net/v2/apps",
    "qs": {
      "q": "name:yourappname"
    },
    "json": true,
    "headers": {
      "accept": "application/json",
      "authorization": "bearer " + token
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.resources[0].metadata.guid);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is assuming you are using Bluemix US South region. You have to adjust the login and api server if using a different region (like https://login.eu-gb.bluemix.net for London).

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/272/apps/get_app_summary.html
```

With the httpclient API, you can get the app names from any language.